# DataFlow Runner failing with error openpyxl module not found error on read_excel

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

When running a dataflow job simple read from GCS.

```
df_excel = p | dataframe.io.read_excel(path=file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

The following error is thrown, openpyxl is  supported according to apachebeam documentation
https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.33.0/apache_beam.dataframe.io.html

What am i missing out? Same works in my local with a default runner

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shricharan/Documents/workspace/tesseract/test_file2.py", line 455, in <module>
    processFiles(site_name='DataPipeline', remote_path=f'bigcommerce/{ENV}', local_path=f'{GCS_FILE_LOCATION}downloads', dodo_processed_files=[], fofo_processed_files=[], pipeline_options=pipeline_options)
  File "/Users/shricharan/Documents/workspace/tesseract/test_file2.py", line 399, in processFiles
    loadData('CategoryPriority', excel_fields = ['name', 'priority', 'channel'], table_name='category_priority3', table_fields=['name', 'priority'], source_channel=channel, file_path=f'{GCS_FILE_LOCATION}{blob.name}', excel_primary_keys=['name', 'channel'], bq_primary_keys=['name', 'channel'], pipeline_options=pipeline_options)
  File "/Users/shricharan/Documents/workspace/tesseract/test_file2.py", line 151, in loadData
    pcoll_excel = (
  File "/Users/shricharan/Documents/workspace/new_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 597, in __exit__
    self.result.wait_until_finish()
  File "/Users/shricharan/Documents/workspace/new_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 1667, in wait_until_finish
    raise DataflowRuntimeException(
apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/_optional.py", line 126, in import_optional_dependency
    module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

Comment: What Apache Beam version did you use to run your job? I tried using `read_excel()` in Beam version 2.33.0 with `DataflowRunner` and I did not encounter the error.

Comment: Used the latest version 2.40.0

Comment: Did you try running `pip install openpyxl` prior to running your pipeline?

Comment: Added it explicitly requirements, even tried to pass that package as install_requires=['openpyxl'], in the setup.py.

Comment: Where are you running the job? Locally, with a cloud service (cloud function, cloud run, etc.)?

Comment: Running it on Dataflow Runner, locally things work, when running it on Dataflow runner getting the above error. Mentioned the same on the question. @RiccoD

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add openpyxl as an [explicit dependency](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/).

Comment: Have already added in comment in the above thread that added it explicitly (install_requires=['openpyxl']), even then had the same issue for the latest version 2.40.0